# Python print non-prime numbers

Tags: python, loops

I have a hackkerank coding challenge to print first n non prime numbers, i have the working code but the problem is that they have a locked code which prints numbers from 1 to n along with the output, in order to pass the test i need to print only the non prime numbers not 1...n numbers along with it. I cant comment the printing part of 1...n as it is blocked. please let me know the idea to print only 1st n non prime numbers:

here is my solution:

```
def manipulate_generator(generator, n):
    if n>1:
    ls=[1]
    for elm in generator:
        if elm>3 and len(ls)<n:
            for k in range(2,elm):
                if elm%k==0 and elm not in ls:
                    ls.append(elm)
                    print(elm)
                    if len(ls)==n:
                        return ls
```

That's the code I added but here is the code that's locked on which I have to write the code above to make it print the number one at a time

```
def positive_integers_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        x = yield n
        if x is not None:
            n = x
        else:
            n += 1

k = int(input())
g = positive_integers_generator()
for _ in range(k):
    n = next(g)
    print(n)
    manipulate_generator(g, n)
```

the point is the for _ in range(k): already prints out number which includes numbers I don't want printed out: This is the desired kind of output I want:for n=10 I want it to print out:
output:

```
1
4
6
8
9
10
12
14
15
16
```

I can't change this code but the one above is what I wrote and can be changed... Pleae help me out... Thanks in anticipation

Comment: You're told to write a function called `manipulate_generator`. It takes a generator as an argument. Have you considered *manipulating that generator*?

Comment: this is what I have done so far to the function: def manipulate_generator(generator, n):
    ls=[1]
    for i in range(2,100):
        for x in range(2,i):
            if i%x == 0 and i not in ls:
              ls.append(i)
              print(i)
        if(len(ls)==n):
            break                             but the problem is that the for _ in range(k): loop is printing the numbers many time instead of jut printing it out once

Comment: it's printing the result out as many times as the while loop is running because the call to the manipulate_generator method is inside...which i feel it's kind of normal but how can i get it to print it out just once as is required of me in the question? thanks

Comment: `manipulate_generator` is not supposed to print anything. It is supposed to manipulate a generator.

Comment: The Hackerrank challenge most likely mentioned something about `send`.

Comment: A hint: In your function, `generator.send(value)` will affect `x = yield n` in the `positive_integers_generator()` function.  If you test `n` you can manipulate the generator using `send` to affect the next value printed.

Comment: look at the code i wrote but it passing just one test:    if n==1:
        print(n)
        return 1
    ls=[1]
    for elm in generator:
        if elm>3 and len(ls)<n:
            for k in range(2,elm):
                if elm%k==0 and elm not in ls:
                    ls.append(elm)
                    print(elm)
                    if len(ls)==n:
                        return ls

Answer (score 1):

Why not to throw away the numbers which we don't need? Look at this solution which I implemented...

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def manipulate_generator(generator, n):
    if is_prime(n+1):
        next(generator)
        manipulate_generator(generator, n+1)
```

Note: I understand that the logic can be improved to make it more efficient. But, its the idea of skipping unnecessary number printing which is important here !

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works quite well. However, just passes 8/12 testes. What kind of improvement do you think that is possible to make? I spent two days trying to figure out and nothing came to my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can print all the numbers from 1 up to the first prime number and then from that first number to the next one until you reach n.

Comment: the point is the for _ in range(k): already prints out number which includes numbers I don't want printed out: This is the desired kind of output I want:for n=10 I want it to print out: 1
4
6
8
9
10
12
14
15
16

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your hackerrank situation, but printing the first N **non-prime** numbers efficiently can be done this way.

```
def non_prime_numbers_till_n(n):
    primes = set()
    for num in range(2,number + 1):
        if num > 1:
           for i in range(2, math.sqrt(num)):
               if (num % i) == 0:
                  break
               else:
                  primes.add(num)
     result = []
     for i in range(1, n):
         if i not in primes:
            result.append(i)
     return result
```

Depending on what your online editor expects you can either print them, or store them in a list and return the list.

Also bear in mind, you can only check upto the sqrt of the number to determine if its a prime or not.

Comment: the point is the for _ in range(k): already prints out number which includes numbers I don't want printed out: This is the desired kind of output I want:for n=10 I want it to print out: 1 4 6 8 9 10 12 14 15 16

Comment: Thanks, but maybe you should read the question again and try to understand it.... I want each element to be printed out without repetition as the output.... as I have described in the question above... the problem am having now i that it prints mt desired output k times which is not what I want...I want it printed out once

Comment: it;s printing the result out as many times as the while loop is running because the call to the manipulate_generator method is inside...which i feel it's kind of normal but how can i get it to print it out just once as is required of me in the question? thanks

Comment: I don't have a while loop or a generator in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually came up with this answer which I believe should solve it but id there;s a better way to solve it please add your answers:

```
def manipulate_generator(generator, n):
    for num in range(3,100000):
        for q in range(2,num):
            if num%q==0 and num>n:
                generator.send(num-1)
                return
```

this link [python generator](http://codetheory.in/how-to-access-the-elements-of-a-generator-object-in-python/) helped me to understand python generator

Comment: it's not meeting the time limit for the challenge

Answer (score 0):

I just solved that right now. Like Swapnil Godse said you need to deal with all special cases to optimize computations. This link might be helpful: [click here.](https://dev.to/alebian/infinite-list-of-prime-numbers-using-python-generators-5fdc)

Here is the solution:

```
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(n):
    if (n <= 1):
        return False
    if (n == 2):
        return True
    if (n % 2 == 0):
        return False

    i = 3
    while i <= sqrt(n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i = i + 2

    return True

def manipulate_generator(g, n):
    if is_prime(n+1):
        next(g)
        manipulate_generator(g, n+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prime = int(input('Please enter the range: '))

prime_number = []

for num in range(prime):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_number.append(num)
        
print(f'Prime numbers in range {prime} is {prime_number}')

all_number = []
for i in range(2,prime+1):
    all_number.append(i)



Non_prime_number = []

for element in all_number:
    if element not in prime_number:
        Non_prime_number.append(element)

print(f'Non Prime numbers in range {prime} is {Non_prime_number}')
```